# Function Template cannot be called on from main as there is no matching function call

Tags: c++

For some reason my code cannot call on my template... XCODE keeps telling me that there is no matching function for call to "extra"

```
template<class T>
T extra(T prompt, T low, T high) {.....}

int main()
{
string prompt = "hi"
int low = 5;
int high = 50;

int value = extra(prompt, low, high);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
T extra(T prompt, T low, T high) { ... }
```

defines a function that takes 3 parameters of type `T`, so all the parameters must be of the *same* type. This is not the case when you call

```
//                string  int  int
int value = extra(prompt, low, high);
```

Think of it like this: You can replace all the `T` with `std::string` or replace all of them with `int`. In both cases the parameters don't match.

However I can't propose a solution, because I'm not sure what you intend to do.